# In how many ways 13 non distinguishable objects can be distributed among 7 persons so that every person get at least one object.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> > In how many ways $13$ non distinguishable objects can be distributed among $7$
> > persons so that every person get at least one object and atleast one person gets $4$
> > objects but not more.

**My Approach:** $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7=13$

such that $1\leq x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7 \leq 4$

I used Generating Function Method that is

coefficient of $x^{13}$ in expansion of $(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)^7$

$\implies$ coefficient of $x^6$ in expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^7$

$\implies$ coefficient of $x^6$ in $\bigl(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x})^7$

$\implies$ coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1-x^4)^7 (1-x)^{-7}$

$\implies$ Coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1-7 \cdot x^4+...){7+r-1 \choose 7-1}x^r$

$\implies$ Coefficient of $x^6$ in ${6+r \choose 6}x^r-7{6+r \choose 6}x^{4+r}$

After putting $r=6$ and $r=2$, I got

=${12 \choose 6}-7\cdot {8 \choose6}=728$

**Which Does not match with given answer**

**I Just want to know Why Am I not getting Answer with this method. I know other method to solve the problem**

Comment: I don't see how you accounted for "*at least one person gets 4 objects*"

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by JMoravitz, your solution distributes identical objects to persons such that each gets at least one object and maximum of $4$ objects. What it does not ensure is that at least one person gets $4$ objects. There are multiple ways to fix it, one of them being -

$ \text {Coefficient} [(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^7, x^{13}] -  \text {Coefficient} [(x+x^2+x^3)^7, x^{13}]$

$ = 728 - 357 = 371$

The second term gives you all arrangements where no person gets $4$ objects and we subtract it from  number of arrangements without this specific restriction.